# JavaScript/JQuery code which makes word appear at random places of the screen doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I asked for help sometime ago to make a word appear at random different places of the screen with each mouse click by using javascript and/or jquery.
I adapted a code that was shared with me but it is nor working and I can't find the problem.

This is what I've got in my HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<h4>Here is everywhere</h4>
<h5>(it depends where you are)</h5>
</header>

<div class="here">
<p>Here!</p>
</div>

<button>
click me!
</button>

<script src="javascript.js" type="application/javascript"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Helvetica;
src: url(Helvetica CE Regular.ttf);
}

h4, h5, p {
font-family: helvetica;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
}

h4, h5{
color: #FFF;

}

h4{
font-size: 51px;
line-height:40px;
}

p{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

header{
background-color:#000;
width: 100vw;
height:16vh;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow: hidden;
}

body{
width: 100vw;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.here {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
background: red;
padding: 1em;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

And this is my Java and JQuery:

var button;
button = document.getElementById('button');

```
$('button').click(function(){
$('.here').css({
top: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
left: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
})
})
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected!!!

Comment: Really? It is not working on my browser tho... I click the button and the word doesn't move nor changes its position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible reason would be that your code is running before the DOM is fully loaded. Wrap your code with `$(document).ready(function(){`, this will ensure that the code placed inside will be executed only after the DOM is fully loaded.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var button; 
  button = document.getElementById('button');

  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.here').css({
      top: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
      left: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  src: url(Helvetica CE Regular.ttf);
}

h4, h5, p {
  font-family: helvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h4, h5{
  color: #FFF;
}

h4{
  font-size: 51px;
  line-height:40px;
}

p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

header{
  background-color:#000;
  width: 100vw;
  height:16vh;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.here {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: red;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Here is everywhere</h4>
<h5>(it depends where you are)</h5>


<div class="here">
<p>Here!</p>
</div>

<button>
click me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your jQuery in `$(document).ready()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('.here').css({
            top: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
            left: (100 * Math.random()).toString() + "%",
        });
    });
});
```

I made a quick pen: https://codepen.io/baronson95/pen/vvJXMW

Comment: Thank you but it still isn't working... https://gyazo.com/49253c44a198c3b50a8c58c604c87ef9